# Plotly JSON Chart Schema - Weird behaviour of the line graph

Tags: python, json, flask, plotly

I am working with Flask, trying to plot some charts using plotly Json Chart Schema.
The df is just a Date (fecha) column (date type) and the second one (cantidad_fardos) is an integer, there is Not NULL values in the df.

This is my JSON:

```
"data" : [
            {
                "line" : {"color" : "red",
                            "width" : 2,
                            "shape" : "spline"},
                "mode" : "lines+markers",
                "name" : "fardos",
                "type" : "scatter",
                "x" : df2['fecha'],
                "y" : df2['cantidad_fardos']                           
            }],
        "layout" : {
            "title" : "Segundo grafico",
        }
    }
```

And the result Im getting is:
[image]

The second point is joining the last one, I can't figure it out why is having this kind of behaviour. I just want a basic line chart and the points must be joined based on the date.

Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. My problem was that my df wasn't ordered!!